# Special string padding characters ignored by regex's

Tags: python, regex, unicode, nlp, text-processing

I am parsing text which involves filtering out special characters or gaps of whitespaces in order for the string to be categorized correctly. The problem is the original string's index maps back to other metadata (x,y coordinates of OCRd text in an image). Once the keywords are categorized correctly, I would like to map back to the original pre-processed string via an index (beginning and end), as opposed to the keyword itself. The location is more important than the keyword, as the keyword is not necessarily unique.

A lot of the code is looks like:

`filtered_text = re.sub(\s{5,}, '', line)
mobj = re.match(my_pat, filtered_text)
return (mobj.start(0), mobj.end(0))`

I'm wondering if instead of replacing with an empty string, can it be replaced with a special "padding/filler" character? This special character would satisfy the two requirements:

(1) it takes up space so that:

```
len(line) == len(filtered_line)
```

(2) it is ignored by downstream pattern regex matches.

Is there any special unicode characters that I can use or can something in the re module be set to ignore a specific character?

Also, I cannot merge the substitution pattern with the match pattern, as different parts of the code are abstracted from each other. The above example is very simple -- the actual two independent parts of code are very complicated.

Comment: You could use `\0`, which probably won't show up anywhere. What format is this?

Comment: This is utf-8. Here's what I'm trying:
 `t = 'this is a\0string' 
mobj=re.search('(.*astring)', t)`
 I've tried a lot of permutations but the search still fails. Any thoughts?

Comment: I meant the name of the format you're trying to parse. Is it generated by Tesseracts?

Answer (score 0):

While you are replacing the white space, you need keep a mapping from the transformed positions back to the original positions.

```
def sub_with_mapping(pattern, repl, string):
    mapping = dict()
    source_index = [0]
    target_index = [0]
    target = []
    #
    def append_segment(original_len, text, keep_positions):
        for i in range(0, len(text)):
            mapping[target_index[0] + i] = source_index[0] + (i if keep_positions else 0)
        target.append(text)
        target_index[0] += len(text)
        source_index[0] += original_len
    #
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, string):
        # Append text between previous and this match
        prefix = string[source_index[0]:match.start()]
        append_segment(len(prefix), prefix, True)
        # Append replacement text
        replacement = repl
        if callable(replacement):
            replacement = replacement(match)
        append_segment(len(match.group(0)), replacement, False)
    # Append text after last match
    suffix = string[source_index[0]:]
    append_segment(len(suffix), suffix, True)
    return ''.join(target), mapping
```

```
>>> sub_with_mapping(r'\w+', 'x', 'foo --- bar --- baz')
('x --- x --- x', {0: 0, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 5: 7, 6: 8, 7: 11, 8: 12, 9: 13, 10: 14, 11: 15, 12: 16})
```

You can then do your matching on the returned string, and map the indexes back to your original string.

Note that, if your replacements are longer than one characters, you would have several indexes mapped back to the same original index.

If your strings are very long (>1 MB?), you might want to optimize the data-structure. Maybe you could use ranges?